# Webpack / Babel / React build error: "Unknown option: foo/node_modules/react/react.js.Children"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to build a project with webpack and react with this webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/less/main.less',
    './app/main.js',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'dist/main.js'
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),

        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!less"
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

I am sure I have the needed pm modules too and have webpack installed, however when running webpack I get:

```
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/me/foo/app/main.js: Unknown option: foo/node_modules/react/react.js.Children
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also paste your main.js?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to install [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react):

```
$ npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

Comment: Don't be sorry. Nowhere it's said this NPM package needs to be installed.

Comment: wait, why do you need that package? It installs flow support, which you may or may not be using. Is it that you need syntax-jsx?

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. Where does it say you have to install this?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I got the error **after** I uninstalled an old npm module I wasn't using in my project anymore. Which was weird because I wasn't using it anywhere - how could uninstalling something that isn't used anywhere cause an error?

Turns out that one of that modules *sub-dependencies* had babel-preset-react, which I had missed installing to my own project when I started it. Thus, uninstalling that package also uninstalled the critical babel-preset-react!

For over a year, my react app could compile thanks to another package's sub-dependency...

---

So yes, installing babel-preset-react solved the issue for me.